# Invalid <url-pattern> * in filter mapping. during deployment of grails 3 app on glassfish

Tags: grails, glassfish, url-mapping

When depliying a Grails 3 App on a Glassfish 4.1.1 container, I'm getting the next error code:

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> * in filter mapping.
```

My UrlMappings.groovy:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
        "404"(view:'/notFound')
    }
}
```

Am I missing any configuration?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably down to this default configuration:

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-controllers/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugins/web/controllers/ControllersGrailsPlugin.groovy#L82

Which defaults to this value:

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-core/src/main/groovy/grails/config/Settings.groovy#L185

Try setting this in `grails-app/conf/application.yml`:

```
grails:
   web:
     servlet:
         path: "/"
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.